# Why can't Django see my static files?

Tags: python, django, sass, django-cms

I am trying to implement sass_processor in my django_cms site and am getting a weird error.

```
Unable to locate file mysite/static/scss/main.scss while rendering tag 'sass_src' in template /Users/USER/Work/DIR/APP/SITE/mysite/templates/base.html
```

I have followed the latest Django CMS install instructions and have everything set up and working perfectly. I have tried importing static css files and it works fine.

for example in my base.html

```
<link href="{% static 'myapp/static/css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Imports perfectly

I have made sure to include sass_tags in my template

I have followed the instructions on the github page here:
https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor

My sass import is as follows:

```
<link href="{% sass_src 'myapp/static/scss/main.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/x-scss" />
```

My static file structures are as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'static')
SASS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'static', 'scss')
SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = SASS_ROOT

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'static'),
)

SASS_PROCESSOR_INCLUDE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite', 'static'),
    SASS_ROOT
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder',
)

SASS_PROCESSOR_ENABLED = True
```

My file structure is as follows:

```
|+env/
`~tate/
  |+media/
  |~mysite/
  | |~static/
  | | |+css/
  | | `~scss/
  | |   `-main.scss
  | |+templates/
  | |-__init__.py
  | |-__init__.pyc
  | |-settings.py
  | |-settings.pyc
  | |-urls.py
  | |-urls.pyc
  | |-wsgi.py
  | `-wsgi.pyc
  |+static/
  |-manage.py*
  `-requirements.txt
```

I feel like I have missed some kind of path configuration but I'm not sure where it could be as I followed the Django CMS tutorial and the instructions outlined on the sass_processor page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello Daniel, do you get this error in your local machine? or on a remote server?

Comment: The most obvious question, but are you sure that you provided correct path? Could you paste your static file structures? Did you set SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT variable?

Comment: @mateuszb I have updated hopefully this helps

Comment: @Paulo just my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the same error message. Django couldn't find my scss file, but it wasn't anything related to `CssFinder` as I firstly thought, the problem was I wasn't providing a valid path in my HTML for `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder`, that is the one trying to find the scss file.

Make sure you provide a valid path for your `FileSystemFinder` configuration, as the paths you're reffering to don't match: your error says `mysite/static/scss/main.scss` while your HTML link shows `myapp/static/scss/main.scss`. I don't know if this is just a typo or your error doesn't take place here.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the type of your SASS import to "*text/css*". The "*text/x-scss*" type is used by **django-compressor**, but not by **django-sass-processor**.

Your new SASS import then becomes:

```
<link href="{% sass_src 'myapp/static/scss/main.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```